# Nagios PNP4Nagios Averaging Integer Value?

Tags: powershell, nagios

I have a powershell script in nagios which returns an integer using the built-in Windows netstat command. The command is as follows:

```
$conns = nestat -na | select-string -pattern "ESTABLISHED"
$NumberOfConnections = $conns.count
$NumberOfConnections
```

The output is something like:

```
123
```

Works as expected. But when I graph it Nagios and run the check every three minutes, the result is graphed in pnp4nagios like 120.657 or 125.124 (it's averaging the value like a float instead of graphing the integer).

Does anyone know how I can force Nagios and PNP4Nagios RRDtool graphing for a specific service check to not average or round a result? In fact, because it's an integer, I don't want any decimal points at all. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you saving your data, and how are you feeding it to PNP4Nagios? Seems to me that the delimiter is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should check the perfdata itsself returned by the check - should be something like `'key'=value` following valid perfdata specifications.

Then get an idea how pnp4nagios templates work - depending on your version (0.6 is actively developed), look e.g. here: [1]

The templates will be looked up by their check command name by default (so if you did not create one for your custom check, there's likely the default.php template used).

Depending how you installed pnp4nagios, the templates directory can be found below `$prefix/share/templates.dist` - place yours into `$prefix/share/templates` to prevent them being lost during upgrades. Now copy the `$prefix/share/templates.dist/default.php` to `$prefix/share/templates/<yourcheckcommandname>.php` and start edit that (make sure webserver's user may open it).

You'll see that this is just creating a call to `rrdtool`, appended strings in php code mostly. Regarding your problem:

- you do not want to have AVG, but the current value in your legend
- floating point formatting isn't desired

Looking at

```
$def[$KEY]  = rrd::def     ("var1", $VAL['RRDFILE'], $VAL['DS'], "AVERAGE");
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::gradient("var1", "3152A5", "BDC6DE", rrd::cut($VAL['NAME'],16), 20);
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::line1   ("var1", $_LINE );
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::gprint  ("var1", array("LAST","MAX","AVERAGE"), "%3.4lf%S".$VAL['UNIT']);
```

In the first line you'll define `var1` as "AVERAGE". Play around and set that to "LAST" if that consolidation fits better when drawing the graph.

The last line with `gprintf` follows `printf` syntax, where `lf` will be a double with precision 4 and 3 numbers at front (3.4) [2]
Changing `%lf` to `%d` (integer) will likely resolve the issue with the legend.

You may change that as follows e.g.

```
$def[$KEY]  = rrd::def     ("var1", $VAL['RRDFILE'], $VAL['DS'], "LAST");
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::gradient("var1", "3152A5", "BDC6DE", rrd::cut($VAL['NAME'],16), 20);
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::line1   ("var1", $_LINE );
$def[$KEY] .= rrd::gprint  ("var1", array("LAST","MAX","AVERAGE"), "%d %S".$VAL['UNIT']);
```

There's even further possibilities on those templates - like scaling the y-axis, etc - that's just `rrdtool` syntax then.

For printing the latest value how Nagios/Icinga Core sent the perfdata to PNP4Nagios you can also use another trick - pnp stores additional data which does not fit the rrd storage in its own `*.xml` files. Those xml files are updated with every normal rrd update run by `process_perfdata.pl` then.
One of them is "ACT" (check [1]) which can be accessed on the first datasource just like `$ACT[1]` in the template code, and then be passed as comment string to the rrdtool call.

```
$def[$KEY] .= "COMMENT:\"Current $ACT[$key]\\n\" ";"
```

[1] http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/tpl

[2] http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Unfortunately changing the DS value from average to LAST did not work nor did changing the %lf to %d. When I changed AVERAGE to LAST i got the error: "ERROR: the RRD does not contain an RRA matching the chosen CF". If I keep it as average, but change the %3.4lf to %d, it says "STDOUT => ERROR: bad format for GPRINT in '%d %s Last'. I should mention that this is copied from the default.php template. I feel like it's close, just a syntax or formatting issue now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tbh I did not test it, just collected some samples. In general, you should get to know how the rrdtool printf syntax works. And well, if LAST does not work out, use the $ACT[1] as COMMENT then. That works in my custom templates for the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [to specify `LAST` in the .php template as described in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678451/nagios-pnp4nagios-averaging-integer-value#17011056), you'll need to first create LAST as a consolidation function in the pnp4nagios file "rra.cfg".  There should be existing values for AVERAGE, MIN, and MAX in that file already.

In my system that file did not exist, but I did have `rra.cfg-sample`.  I copied `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/rra.cfg-sample` to `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/rra.cfg`.  Then I edited `/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/rra.cfg` to add:

```
RRA:LAST:0.5:1:2880
RRA:LAST:0.5:5:2880
RRA:LAST:0.5:30:4320
RRA:LAST:0.5:360:5840
```

Note that the numbers correspond to my step value of 60 seconds (I poll every minute), so you should match the existing values in your rra.cfg file.

Then you must delete the existing RRD files and let pnp4nagios recreate them.

The new RRD files should now have an additional "cf" (consolidation function).  The new RRD files will also be 25% larger.

```
[server]# rrdtool dump Interface_Drops_-_MET_ATL1_VIRL-FLAT.rrd | grep cf

            <cf> AVERAGE </cf>
            <cf> AVERAGE </cf>
            <cf> AVERAGE </cf>
            <cf> AVERAGE </cf>
            <cf> MAX </cf>
            <cf> MAX </cf>
            <cf> MAX </cf>
            <cf> MAX </cf>
            <cf> MIN </cf>
            <cf> MIN </cf>
            <cf> MIN </cf>
            <cf> MIN </cf>
            <cf> LAST </cf>
            <cf> LAST </cf>
            <cf> LAST </cf>
            <cf> LAST </cf>
```